# Swift - unwrap UILabel.text

Tags: ios, swift

```
   let myLabel:UILabel = UILabel(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44))
   myLabel.text = "Primary"                
   print(myLabel.text)
```

results in:

Optional("First")

I can do print(myLabel.text!) but is this good practice to force unwrap the Optional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your code it's ok, because you actually know that you set some text. But usually you should do something like this:

```
if let text = myLabel.text {
   print(text)
}
```

This will print your text only if it exists.

Comment: Should this not be "guard let text = " ?

Comment: you could also use guard if you want for swift 2 only, but this is the usual way to check if an optional contains any value

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the nil-coalescing operator

```
let myLabel:UILabel = UILabel(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44))
myLabel.text = "Primary"
print(myLabel.text ?? "")
```

Playgrounds are good for working these things out.

[image]

Comment: You don't need to interpolate the label. A simple `print(myLabel.text ?? "")` should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Swift 2:

```
func print(){
    guard let text = myLabel.text else {
    return 
   }  
  print(text); 
 }
```

For the Swift < 2

```
if let text = myLabel.text {
print(text) 
}
```

To answer your question:

It is always better to check if the optional isn't null.
Because if you don't and it is null your app will crash. 
Usually I use if let to check this...

```
var userInput

func doSth(){
//do Sth
if let _ = myLabel.text {
userInput = myLabel.text 
} else {
myLabel.text = "Welcome" 
}
//do Sth 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the nil-coalescing operator. It basically is a way to easily return an unwrapped optional, or a default value.

```
let myLabel:UILabel = UILabel(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44))
myLabel.text = "Primary"
var text:String? = myLabel.text ?? nil
print("\(text)")
```